# Bare metal Nginx controller with Services as Node port not working

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, kubernetes-networking

Hi i have use Nginx controller both community and Nginx repo both works for in cloud with `LoadBalancer` service. Where as Nginx controller both community and Nginx repo both dose not work with service `Nodeport` "error 404".

`404 Not Found`

Service Type Nodeport

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
    - name: https
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
```

Comment: Can you please add the commands or URL that you used to see the `404`?
Can you also provide the output of `kubectl get svc -n ingress-nginx ingress-nginx`?

Comment: How did you access `NodePort` service? You can access `NodePort` Service, from outside the cluster, by requesting `<NodeIP>:<NodePort>`.

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior of a NGINX Ingress Controller is to reply with a default backed that replies with a `404 - default backend`: basically, it's a running Deployment resource returning that default page.

You can try overriding it passing to Helm a variable override using the path `defaultBackend.image.repository` as described in the [README](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nginx-ingress)